# Understanding the quotient of $S^2$ by a non-free action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550033/quotient-of-a-riemannian-manifold-by-a-non-free-group-action) and wondered about a similar thing.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2$ act on $S^2$ by letting the non-trivial element take
$$(x,y,z)\mapsto(-x,-y,z).$$
This action is not free, so one would expect something to go "wrong" with the quotient space $S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$.

On the surface, it seems like $S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a nice space; it is homeomorphic to $S^2$, which is a topological manifold. However, the north and south ends of $S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ seem somewhat crushed and "conical", instead of smooth. But I'm not sure how to match this intuition with something rigorous.

**Question 1:** Does $S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ inherit a smooth structure from $S^2$? If not, why not?

**Question 2:** Is there some precise sense in which the north and south ends of $S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ are conical? (This would seem to assume that $S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ has a natural Riemannian metric; why is this the case?)

Comment: Take this with a huge grain of salt: I don't think the quotient inherits a smooth structure from $\Bbb S^2$, since the fixed points of the action may correspond in the quotient to "boundary points" or to a point which is not in the domain of a coordinate system. I do think it should turn out to be an orbifold, and although I'm really not familiar with those things, I understand that one can define tangent spaces and Riemannian metrics for orbifolds. Since $\Bbb Z_2$ acts by isometries, there should be a "Riemannian metric" (whatever that means now) on the quotient.

Comment: As Ivo Terek said, this is called an [orbifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold). It is similar to the sphere but the two poles are replaces with singular points with neighbourhoods of the form $\Bbb R^2 / \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: The linked question is now answered. tl; dr: The poles of the _Riemannian_ quotient are conical, but there is a smooth _holomorphic_ quotient (the sphere again).